# How can I call html function on click from Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console, google-developers-console

I'm trying to click on a row in a grid on https://www.geoguessr.com/results/eC24Umyej5bNAftC.
The first node has this button:

```
  <div class="results-highscore__player-place">#1</div>
    <div class="results-highscore__player-pin">
      <span class="pin pin--border pin--background-brown pin--border-white">
        <span class="pin__border">
        <img src="/images/auto/48/48/ce/0/plain/pin/11f2be33a614fdce0acb29127ccefd09.png" class="image" alt="Avatar" loading="auto">
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  <div class="results-highscore__player-nick">వేడి గాడిద
  </div>
</div>
```

Via Chrome's console I can inspect the element and found this event listener:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdgZZ.png)

which opens in a new tab to this: https://www.geoguessr.com/_next/static/chunks/4bd0e87d22a2d4e9ba0c1f0ec9581005d2ecff38.c270863a1ded548a2124.js

I've tried to click it but nothing happens:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("results-highscore__cell results-highscore__player-cell ")[0].click
document.getElementsByClassName("results-highscore__cell results-highscore__player-cell ")[0].l.click
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfvpX.png)

Comment: `anHtmlElement.click()` is a function, so you need to use `()` parentheses.